# How to separate absolute value functions when checking for continuity?

Tags: continuity, absolute-value

> $f:[2;\infty)\backslash\{3\}\to\mathbb{R}$, $$f(x):=\frac{|x^2-4x+3|}{x^2-2x-3}=\begin{cases}\frac{(x^2-4x+3)}{x^2-2x-3} & x\geq3\\\frac{-(x^2-4x+3)}{x^2-2x-3} & x<3\end{cases}$$

I see $f$ is undefined in $3$ because the denominator has a zero in this point. So my first thought is actually to factorize $f$ by finding the zeros (e.g. with the p-q-formula): $$f(x)=\frac{|x^2-4x+3|}{x^2-2x-3}=\frac{|(x-1)(x-3)|}{(x-3)(x+1)}=\begin{cases}\frac{(x-1)}{(x+1)} & (x-1)(x-3)\geq0\\\frac{-(x-1)}{(x+1)} & (x-1)(x-3)<0\end{cases}$$
Since $1\notin [2;\infty)$, I only need to consider the critical point $x_0=3$.

Now I want to identify when the absolute value function changes its sign. Approaching $3$ from the left gives (since $x<3$ and $x$ close to $3$): $(x-1)(x-3)<0$. So we are in the second case for the left hand limit. For the right hand limit (since $x>3$) we are in the first case , correct? Is this an efficient method to dissolve absolute value functions like this when checking for continuity?

General question: we also factorized functions like $\frac{1}{4-x^2}$ to examine whether the limit is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ when approaching $x_0=2$ and we factorized functions like $\frac{x^2+5x-24}{x+8}$ just to simplify. So when do I factorize a function when checking for continuity? When the critical value is a zero of the denominator, to simplify or to decide when the absolute value function changes its sign?

Comment: I think you might have a problem with your factorization of the denominator, since $x^2-2x-3=(x+1)(x-3)$ (and not $(x-3)(x+3)$). Apart from that, your reasoning looks very good. And yes, you can factorize in all these settings. You could see factorization as being part of your toolbox, ready to help in all these situations.

Comment: You are on the right track. In general, to remove absolute value bars you check when function is negative or non-negative. When checking for continuity, you check the points where denominator is zero. Factorization helps in both cases.

Comment: @cs89 ah yes, thank you! I've made an edit. So factorizing quadratic equations is always a good idea when checking for continuity?

Comment: When you have a fraction, less. Otherwise, not so much. For example you can tell that $f(x) = 10 x^2 + x + 7$ is continuous without attempting to factorize it.

Comment: $$f(x)\in \Bbb R\Rightarrow x^2-2x-3\ne 0\Rightarrow x \ne -1,3$$

$$f(x)=\frac{|(x-1)(x-3)|}{(x+1)(x-3)}, x\ge 2$$

$$f(x)=\frac{|x^2-4x+3|}{x^2-2x-3}=\begin{cases}\frac{x-1}{x+1} & \underbrace{x^2-4x+3\gt 0, x\ge 2}_{x\gt 3}\\-\frac{x-1}{x+1} & \underbrace{x^2-4x+3 \lt 0,x\ge 2}_{2\le x \lt 3}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @WindSoul how did you conclude $x^2-4x+3>0,x\geq2\Rightarrow x>3$ and $x^2-4x+3<0,x\geq2\Rightarrow x<3$? Did you insert $x>3$ and $x<3$?

Comment: $$x^2-4x+\ge 0\Rightarrow \underbrace{(x\le 1 \text{ or } x\ge 3) \text{ and } f:[2,\infty)-\{3\}}_{x\gt 3}$$ Also $|E(x)|=\left \{ \begin{align}E(x), E(x)\ge 0\\-E(x), E(x)\lt 0\end{align}\right .$.